# I am having errore when trying to access mysql

Tags: mysql

After writing "sudo mysql" on terminal it is giving me this error:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
mysql -u root
mysqladmin -u root password [newpassword]
```